# Ajax. как преобразовать json в массив php

Tags: php, ajax, json, mvc

Делаю запрос:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.trigger',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var that = jQuery(this);
    var event_link = that.data('link');
    var url = '/' + event_link;

    jQuery.post(url, function(data) {
      console.log("++");
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
      console.log("---");
    })
});`
```

Контроллер дергает базу, база отдает массив. Массив я преобразовываю в json отдаю в `data`.

Вопрос: как теперь это добро во вьюшке показать? 
Если без ajax то контроллер отдает на вьюшку массив, который мы проходим в цикле и встраиваем в код. Как быть тут ? Есть ли возможность получить массив php или как грамотно встроить полученные данные в html?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем ты отдаешь данные Ajax'у? Передавай сразу в представление, если ты получил данные через Ajax  то и обрабатывай их через JS потому что представление их не обработает, так как оно уже выведено, чтобы представление обрабатывало данные надо его еще раз загрузить, например обновить страницу. Или я что-то не понял? Если тебе именно надо встроить данные в страницу и не перезагружать то отдавай уже готовый html и встраивай его

Comment: Ситуация фифти фифти. Или я генерю в контроллере весь html и отдаю. Или через js конструировать получается ?

Comment: ну как бы, сам и ответил... либо так, либо так, оба подхода нормальны, а выбор конкретного - зависит от конкретной задачи из соображения следованию принятой архитектуры в проекте